# Issue calling API gateway via Vertx client

Tags: vert.x

I am trying to connect to AWS API gateway using the Vertx Webclient:

```
        HttpRequest<Buffer> request = webClient.postAbs(targetHost);
        request.putHeader("Authorization", auth);
        request.putHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
        request.putHeader("Host", hostName);

        request.sendJson(new JsonObject(jsonData), response -> {
        if (response.succeeded()) {
        final JsonObject result = response.result().bodyAsJsonObject();
        logger.info(result.toString());
        routingContext.response()
        .setStatusCode(200)
        .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .end(result.toString());
        } else {
        logger.error(response.cause().getMessage());
        routingContext.fail(new Exception(response.cause().getMessage()));
        }
        });
```

and always am receiving the same error response i.e. The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.

But if I use a javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget,

```
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(targetHost);

        response=target.request()
        .header("Authorization", auth)
        .header("Content-Type", contentType)
        .header("Host", hostName)
        .post(jsonData,Response.class);
```

I am able to receive a proper response.

Any idea what Vertx web client is doing differently?

Comment: How is `contentSha256` calculated? In the Vert.x example you let vert.x create the json string but in the JAX-RS example it seems to be created manually

Comment: Its usually a json string.. I tried using the same behaviour in both the calls didn't help either way..

Comment: contentSha256 is just a sha256 value for the json string.. one another thing that I found is that Vertx internally is assigning the port like 443 to the hostname which is not required for a typical Rest end point call... Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

So we figured out the issue, turns out the json data that we were using was not being passed properly in the Vertx implementation.

So we can just create a new JSONObject, create the data and use this object to eveluate the aws signature as well as pass the same object in the actual API call.

Thanks!